# Does rejecting an undergraduate admission offer have any effect on my chances of postgraduate admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-kingdom

I am currently an international undergraduate studying in the US. When I was in school, I applied to a few different universities, including some in the UK. Two universities in the UK accepted me and I ended up rejecting them both. I am a freshman but I am strongly considering applying to their graduate schools after I graduate here. I understand that GPA, recommendations etc are very important, but would the fact that I had previously applied and rejected an offer from their undergraduate schools have any effect, negative or positive, on my chances of admission to a postgraduate course? Have I burned any bridges?

I can post the names of the specific universities if it's relevant.

Comment: I added the UK tag since this may depend on how admission practices work there.  In the US, graduate and undergraduate admissions are handled by completely separate parts of the university, and the grad admission committee would have no reason to even be aware that you had ever applied (and even if they were, I see no reason why it should have any bearing on their decision).

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, that's quite reassuring. Is it reasonable to assume that this would be the case in most places worldwide?

Comment: I don't know.  If I did, I would have posted an answer instead of a comment.  It seems to me unlikely that it makes any difference, but I don't have much basis for saying so.

Comment: In the US, I would say it would have absolutely no impact - people apply to any number of schools for either graduate or undergraduate so not accepting entrance to undergrad is not held against you. As well, the two processes are wholly separate. I can't imagine that it is any different in the UK.

Comment: Universities are not uncle Tom and aunt Beth, and you are not their nephew who didn't turn up for their combined 175th birthday. Figuratively speaking. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have worked on admissions councils and I'm 99.9% certain the answer is no.  I doubt they'll even consider whether or not you had previously applied.  I'd be surprised if they even have a way of looking up that information.  The pile of applicants who reject is tossed away pretty quickly, time to move on.

Comment: Data safety regulations might even enforce the disposal of rejected applications after a year or two, and prevent anyone without a court order from accessing them in the meantime.